# Reading RSS feed using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, rss

I'm trying to show the title of my latest stumbleupon item using their RSS feed and jquery.
The function I have is:

```
function get_stumbleupon() {
    $.get("http://rss.stumbleupon.com/user/fredkelly/", function(data) {
        alert(data.title);
    }, "xml");
}
```

Which returns nothing... I just simply want to get a few bits of info about the **single** latest item in the feed - how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a tutorial](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html) on how to do Cross domain ajax with JQuery.

Comment: Within that tutorial make sure to follow the link to the "universal RSS to JSON converter".

Answer (score 1):

Ólafur Waage gave a good cross site request topic, but there is also another post that actually fits better with your [Cross Site RSS reading](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/google-feeds-api-jquery-plugin.html) problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my little script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery.ajax({
   url: "/feed.xml", // RSS url
   success: function(msg){
     jQuery('#blip').html(''); // where to put RSS
     jQuery('entry',msg).slice(0,3).each(function(){ // slice: get only first 3 posts
        var html = '<div>';
        var upd = jQuery('updated', this).text().replace(/[TZ]/g, ' ');
        var upd = jQuery.trim(jQuery('updated', this).text());
        upd = upd.replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/T/," ").replace(/Z/," UTC");
        upd = upd.replace(/([\+-]\d\d)\:?(\d\d)/," $1$2");
        updf = new Date(upd).toLocaleString();
        html += '<p class="post_date">' + updf + '</p>';
        html += '<div class="post_content"><span>' + jQuery('content', this).text() + '</span></div>';
        html += '</div>';
        jQuery(html).appendTo('#blip');
     });
   },
   error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown);}
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous poster (Waage) mentioned, you are probably doing some Cross-site Scripting which is a security violation on most browsers.  What you need to do is create some kind of pass through (the client makes a call to your site, your site downloads another site's content, and returns it to the client).

This is usually pretty easy regardless of whatever server backend you use.  It also enables you to do some advanced features with other people's data, like caching.

Comment: This is basically what's known as a "proxy server" for those not familiar with Richard's solution.