# How to parse atom feed using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to know how to parse atom feed using jquery.

i had feed url like below

```
http://www.google.co.in/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly
```

Below is jsfiddle but it's not working

http://jsfiddle.net/sukumar/sWPkT/

Comment: did you follow the tuto described in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993850/reading-rss-feed-using-jquery ?

Answer (score 3):

To make cross-browser request, see the link I pointed out in my comment.

You can use this code:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.jgfeed.js"></script>
<script>
$.jGFeed('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/26767000.rss',
  function(feeds){
    // Check for errors
    if(!feeds){
      // there was an error
      return false;
    }
    // do whatever you want with feeds here
    for(var i=0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++){
      var entry = feeds.entries[i];
      // Entry title
      entry.title;
    }
  }, 10);
</script>
```

Don't forget to include Google Feeds API plugin (jquery.jgfeed.js)

[Source](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/11/cross-domain-rss-to-json-converter.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you look in your browser's JavaScript console, you'd probably see something among the lines of:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.co.in/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Basically, for security reasons, you can't make an AJAX request from one domain to another. All browsers enforce this.

Comment: Ok. Can we do using jFeed plugin?